# How to handle a unit/integration test that contains too many lines of codes?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, refactoring

In my current company, we have a web-app is being developed in PHP by more than 20 different developers since 2014. Recently, I have heard such complaints from my team members that some of the **unit tests are too bulky** (unreadable and not easy to trace the code inside) and instead of adding new scenarios/methods to the test class, they would like to create new test classes and adding those new scenarios/methods into to the new ones. Let's assume that we have one class as follows:

```
<?php
    class Foo {   
        public function getOne(): string
        public function getAll(): array
        public function validate(): bool
    }
?>
```

and we have an existing unit test class as follows:

```
<?php
    class FooTest {   
        public function testGetOne() {
            // scenario 1
            // scenerio 2
            // scenario 3
            // scenario 4
            // scenario 5
            // scenario 6
            ...
        }
        public function testGetAll() {
            // scenario 1
            // scenario 2
            // scenario 3
            ...
        }
        public function testValidate() {
            // scenario 1
            // scenario 2
            ...
        }
    }
?>
```

As you might see above that we are following some guidelines for test classes:

- The test class name is formed as the original class name + Test postfix
- Inside of the test class, there is one method defined (ex. **testValidate**) for each testable method of the original class.
- Test scenarios are listed in each test method

We are believing that it is good for traceability. On the other hand, there are **test classes that exceed 1000 lines** and we would like to refactor them somehow. To me, questions to tackle are:

1. Is it okay to create multiple unit test classes for one class? If it is, then based on what criteria we should separate them? (For example, should we create a unit test class for each testable function separately **FooValidateTest**?)
2. How we should handle the naming conventions with those test classes? Again, based on which
   rules?
3. How are we gonna avoid copying/past multiple times helper and mock methods for each unit test class?

I would like to hear your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, I think this options is better than an unreadable test class. You can split the tests by functionality, in your case by the methods.
2. The rules for naming test must be a name that reflects what functionality being testing. "GetOneFooTest" can be an example of name.
3. The functionality test classes ("GetOneFootTest"...) extends from a class "FooTestCase", where the setup for all the Foo tests is placed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The only drawback of the point number 3 is that our test framework (PHPUnit) does not allow to run a unit test alone if it extends any other unit test so basically, they should be executed respectively but together :)

Answer (score 0):

A couple more idea for you -

1/ You can do some setup steps in a new layer of class that you extend from - for example, here's one of my more generic test-parent classes that I used to create some general setup, and also code-quality checks for the tests code itself:

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase as PHPUnit_TestCase;
use PHPUnitGoodPractices\Traits as PHPUnitGoodPractices;

/**
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NumberOfChildren)
 */
abstract class TestCase extends PHPUnit_TestCase
{
    use TestCaseTrait;      // setup Mockery
    use \Mockery\Adapter\Phpunit\MockeryPHPUnitIntegration;
    use PHPUnitGoodPractices\ExpectationViaCodeOverAnnotationTrait;
    use PHPUnitGoodPractices\ExpectOverSetExceptionTrait;
    use PHPUnitGoodPractices\IdentityOverEqualityTrait;
    #use PHPUnitGoodPractices\ProphecyOverMockObjectTrait;
}
```

Many of my own tests will extend `Tests\TestCase`.

As I've used in that class, you can also use traits to move common functionality out of the individual test classes. Soem DocBlock annotations, such as [@before](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.0/annotations.html#before), will also run code in the same way as a method like `protected function setUp(): void {}`.

2/ Even more useful may be [@dataProvider](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.0/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit-data-providers) - These return an array of data (or `yield` from a `Generator` method). If your tests are running the same test code against more than a few versions of different data, then using a DataProvider method allows a single test to be called dozens, even hundreds of times with data parameters to the test method.

```
<?php
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class DataTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider additionProvider
     */
    public function testAdd($a, $b, $expected)
    {
        $this->assertSame($expected, $a + $b);
    }

    public function additionProvider()
    {
        return [
            [0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 1],
            [1, 0, 1],
            [1, 1, 3],    // this test would fail
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) - I would say when you gonna refactor your test class, you would have a cleaner and lightweight class, for example, I have a userTest class that contains more than 4000 lines of code. The way I structure my testing folders is the way my project folder has been setup. So for example, if I have App/Repositories/UserRepository then I would have Tests/Repositories/UserTest. It's much more cleaner I'll rather to not divide my tests into different classes. Because Other developers will never understand the reason.

2) - I would suggest using this convention for naming, MethodName_ExpectedBehavior_StateUnderTest, validate_should_throw_an_error_if_X_field_is_missing or you can use PascalCase. 
https://dzone.com/articles/7-popular-unit-test-naming

3) - you can always encapsulate your mock and helper methods in a separate class, You can either define them statically or create a new instance of the class using the setup method in your test class.